# Highcharts and HighMaps are overLapping

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts, overlapping, highmaps

I am using highChart and highMap with div's created as slides.We are using jquery cycle 2 for the slide effect.

After certain time, the charts are overlapping in Mozilla. But in Chrome hidden slides chart disappears,but legend are present. 
Image Link is given below.

https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=709625395825970&set=a.709625732492603.1073741832.100003355489549&type=1&theater

```
Sample Code:
jsp code:
    <div id="cycle-slideshow" style="width: 100%;">

        <div class="container-fluid animated" id="container_<%=i%>" style="opacity: 0.01;width: 100%;">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="container-fluid" id="container">
    <div class="row border-bottom">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-static-top white-bg main_header" role="navigation" style="margin-bottom: 0">
            <div class="header" id="header">
                <div class="col-lg-12"   style="max-height:25px">
                    <div class="col-lg-6">
                        <h2 >
                           <s:property value="name" escape="false"/>
                        </h2> 
                    </div> 
                      <div class="col-lg-6">
                        <h4 class="pull-right push-bottom" style="margin-top:25px;">
                            <span class="timeData" style="text-align:center;"></span>
                        </h4> 

                    </div>   

                </div>

            </div>
         </nav>
    </div>
    <!-------------------header end------------------------>

    <!-------------------------graph and stream area---------------------------->
    <!----------------------left panel start-------------------->
    <div class="wrapper wrapper-content"   style="padding: 6px 5px 20px !important;">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-9" id="graph_area">
                <div class="row_custom">
                   <div class="row">
                     <div class="col-lg-12">
                        <div class="ibox float-e-margins" style="margin-bottom:14px;">
                            <div class="ibox-title graph_header">

                                <h5><s:property value="settings[1].elementName" escape="false"/></h5>
                            </div>
                            <div class="ibox-content"  style="padding-bottom:4px;">

                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-lg-12" style="padding:4px;" id="<s:property value="settings[1].elementId"/>_<s:property value="settings[1].id"/>_<s:property value="id"/>" >

                                    </div>

                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row" >
                    <div class="col-lg-6">
                        <div class="row" style="margin-left:1px!important;">
                             <div class="ibox float-e-margins">
                            <div class="ibox-title graph_header">

                                <h5><s:property value="settings[3].elementName"/></h5>
                            </div>
                            <div class="ibox-content"  style="padding-bottom:4px;">
                                 <div class="row" >
                                    <div class="col-lg-12" id="<s:property value="settings[3].elementId"/>_<s:property value="settings[3].id"/>_<s:property value="id"/>"  style="display:inline-block;">

                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                    </div>

                    </div>

                    <div class="col-lg-6">
                        <div class="ibox float-e-margins">
                            <div class="ibox-title graph_header">

                                <h5><s:property value="settings[4].elementName"/></h5>
                            </div>
                            <div class="ibox-content" style="padding-bottom:14px;">

                                <div class="row">

                                    <div class="col-lg-12"  style="padding:4px;display:inline-block;" id="<s:property value="settings[4].elementId"/>_<s:property value="settings[4].id"/>_<s:property value="id"/>"  >
                                        //area for map
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
              </div>

            </div>
            <!----------------------left panel End-------------------->
              <!----------------------right panel start-------------------->
            <div class="col-lg-3" id="data_stream_div" >
                <div class="row">
                     <div class="ibox float-e-margins">
                    <div class="ibox-title graph_header">
                        <h5><s:property value="settings[2].elementName"/></h5>
                    </div>
                    <div class="ibox-content" id="temp_1_stream" style="padding-left:1px!important;">
                        <div>
                            <div class="feed-activity-list" style="padding:4px;" id="<s:property value="settings[2].elementId"/>_<s:property value="settings[2].id"/>_<s:property value="id"/>"  >
                                //area for table
                            </div>

                        </div>

                    </div>
                </div>

                </div>

            </div>
            <!----------------------right panel End---------------------->
        </div>
    </div>
    <!---------------------graph area------------------>


</div>
            </div>
        </div>


        <div class="container-fluid animated" id="container_<%=i%>" style="opacity: 0.01;width: 100%;">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="container-fluid" id="container">
    <div class="row border-bottom">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-static-top white-bg main_header" role="navigation" style="margin-bottom: 0">
            <div class="header" id="header">
                <div class="col-lg-12"   style="max-height:25px">
                    <div class="col-lg-6">
                        <h2 >
                           <s:property value="name" escape="false"/>
                        </h2> 
                    </div> 
                      <div class="col-lg-6">
                        <h4 class="pull-right push-bottom" style="margin-top:25px;">
                            <span class="timeData" style="text-align:center;"></span>
                        </h4> 

                    </div>   

                </div>

            </div>
         </nav>
    </div>
    <!-------------------header end------------------------>

    <!-------------------------graph and stream area---------------------------->
    <!----------------------left panel start-------------------->
    <div class="wrapper wrapper-content"   style="padding: 6px 5px 20px !important;">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-9" id="graph_area">
                <div class="row_custom">
                   <div class="row">
                     <div class="col-lg-12">
                        <div class="ibox float-e-margins" style="margin-bottom:14px;">
                            <div class="ibox-title graph_header">

                                <h5><s:property value="settings[1].elementName" escape="false"/></h5>
                            </div>
                            <div class="ibox-content"  style="padding-bottom:4px;">

                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-lg-12" style="padding:4px;" id="<s:property value="settings[1].elementId"/>_<s:property value="settings[1].id"/>_<s:property value="id"/>" >

                                    </div>

                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row" >
                    <div class="col-lg-6">
                        <div class="row" style="margin-left:1px!important;">
                             <div class="ibox float-e-margins">
                            <div class="ibox-title graph_header">

                                <h5><s:property value="settings[3].elementName"/></h5>
                            </div>
                            <div class="ibox-content"  style="padding-bottom:4px;">
                                 <div class="row" >
                                    <div class="col-lg-12" id="<s:property value="settings[3].elementId"/>_<s:property value="settings[3].id"/>_<s:property value="id"/>"  style="display:inline-block;">

                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                    </div>

                    </div>

                    <div class="col-lg-6">
                        <div class="ibox float-e-margins">
                            <div class="ibox-title graph_header">

                                <h5><s:property value="settings[4].elementName"/></h5>
                            </div>
                            <div class="ibox-content" style="padding-bottom:14px;">

                                <div class="row">

                                    <div class="col-lg-12"  style="padding:4px;display:inline-block;" id="<s:property value="settings[4].elementId"/>_<s:property value="settings[4].id"/>_<s:property value="id"/>"  >
                                        //area for piechart
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
              </div>

            </div>
            <!----------------------left panel End-------------------->
              <!----------------------right panel start-------------------->
            <div class="col-lg-3" id="data_stream_div" >
                <div class="row">
                     <div class="ibox float-e-margins">
                    <div class="ibox-title graph_header">
                        <h5><s:property value="settings[2].elementName"/></h5>
                    </div>
                    <div class="ibox-content" id="temp_1_stream" style="padding-left:1px!important;">
                        <div>
                            <div class="feed-activity-list" style="padding:4px;" id="<s:property value="settings[2].elementId"/>_<s:property value="settings[2].id"/>_<s:property value="id"/>"  >
                                //area for table
                            </div>

                        </div>

                    </div>
                </div>

                </div>

            </div>
            <!----------------------right panel End---------------------->
        </div>
    </div>
    <!---------------------graph area------------------>


</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


code for slider:
function getslider(){
    $('#cycle-slideshow').cycle({
        timeout: 90000,
        slides: '> div',
        fx:'fade'
    });

    $( '#cycle-slideshow' ).on( 'cycle-after', function( event, opts ) {
        console.log("lastRunTime      "+lastRunTime);
        console.log("timedifference   "+((lastRunTime-event.timeStamp)/1000));
        lastRunTime=event.timeStamp;
    });
}
code for piechart:
function getShareOfVoice() {

        $.ajax({
            type:"POST",
            dataType:"json",
            url:'<s:url value="XXXXXX',
            data:{sampledata : sampledate},
            cache: false,
            async:"false",
            success:function(data) {

                console.log("in success for share of voice");

            var vals = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data)); 
            if(vals.data.length>0){
            var dataArray = vals.data;
            var overallseries = [];

            overallShareOfVoiceOptions.chart.renderTo = divid;
                for ( var pos = 0; pos < dataArray.length; pos++) {
                    var d = dataArray[pos];
                    var dd = {};
                    var legend_icon = " ";
                    if (d.pic != null
                            && typeof d.pic !== "undefined"
                            && d.pic.length > 0) {
                        legend_icon = '<img style="width: 45px; height: 30px" src="'+d.pic+'" >';
                    } else {
                        legend_icon = d.name;
                    }

                    dd.color = d.cssStyle;
                    dd.y = d.count;
                    dd.name = legend_icon;
                    overallseries.push(dd);
                }

                overallShareOfVoiceOptions.series[0].data = overallseries;
                if (overallseries.length > 0) {
                    var shareOfVoiceOverallGraph = new Highcharts.Chart(
                            overallShareOfVoiceOptions);
                }

                if (draw !== true) {
                    progressbar(divid);
                }
                setTimeout(function() {
                    getShareOfVoice();
                }, 5 * 60 * 1000);

            }
        },error:function(data){

                setTimeout(function() {
                    getShareOfVoice();
                }, 2 * 60 * 1000);
            }

        });

    }

    code for highMap:
    function getRegionChart() {
        $.ajax({   
            type:"POST",
            url:'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
            dataType:'json',
            data : {sampledata : sampledata},

            success : function(data){

                var regions = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data)); 

                if(regions.length > 0){

                        $('#' + divid).highcharts('Map',{
                            title : {
                                text : null
                            },

                            subtitle : {
                                text : null
                            },

                            mapNavigation : {
                                enabled : false,
                                buttonOptions : {
                                    verticalAlign : 'bottom'
                                }
                            },
                            legend : {
                                align : 'left',
                                layout : 'vertical',
                                verticalAlign : 'middle',
                                y : 10,
                                floating : true,
                                borderWidth : 0,
                                backgroundColor : 'white',

                            },
                            colorAxis : {
                                min : 0,
                                minColor : '#cccc00',
                                maxColor : '#666600'
                            },
                            navigation : {
                                menuItemStyle : {
                                    fontSize : '10px'
                                },
                                buttonOptions : {
                                    enabled : false
                                }

                            },

                            credits : {
                                enabled : false
                            },
                            series : [ {
                                data : regions,
                                mapData : Highcharts.maps['countries/in/custom/in-all-disputed'],
                                joinBy : 'hc-key',
                                name : 'State',
                                states : {
                                    hover : {
                                        color : '#BADA55'
                                    }
                                },
                                dataLabels : {
                                    enabled : true,
                                    formatter : function() {
                                        if(!(this.point.options["show"]))
                                            return;

                                        return this.point.value+ "%";
                                    }
                                }
                            } ]
                        });

                        setTimeout(function() {
                            getRegionChart();
                        }, 5*60 *1000);


                }
            },error : function(data) {

                setTimeout(function() {
                    getRegionChart();
                },2*60 * 1000);
            }
        });

    }
```

Comment: Can you share your code on jsfiddle or here instead of sharing a screenshot on facebook?

Comment: What is `divid` ? I think you are using the same container for all of the charts and that's the result. Make sure charts are created in the different container. Also, if this won't help, live demo would be great. I'm pretty sure nobody wants to debug hundreds of lines ;)